# Searching for strings in list

Tags: python, string

I have to create a function that takes a list of integers, strings, and booleans as an input. It is then takes the strings and prints them out as one sentence. This is my function so far:

```
def sentenceGenerator(a):
    newList = []
    for string in a:
        if string == str
            newList.append(string)
    print(newList)
```

And this is how I use it:

```
sentenceGenerator(["Mulan", "and", 5, "Aladdin", "is", True, "Quality"])
```

I know the if statement is not correct but I don't know how else to search.

Comment: just use `is type(string) == str`

Comment: What do you think this does: `if string == str` ?

Comment: ha ha I don't know man I am new and can't figure out what's what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
source = ["Mulan", "and", 5, "Aladdin", "is", True, "Quality"]
[word for word in source if isinstance(word, str)]
```

and even

```
' '.join([word for word in source if isinstance(word, str)])
```

to get a single sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In following part:

```
string == str
```

You are comparing an item with `str` type and since the `==` operation will compare the `string`'s value the preceding statement would be `False`.

If you want to check the type of an object you can use `isinstance()` built-in function.

And as a more pyhtonic way you can use a list comprehension to get the string form your list and pass the result to `str.join()` function with a proper delimiter in order to join the words:

```
>>> ' '.join([item for item in l if isinstance(item, str)])
'Mulan and Aladdin is Quality'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter to find the strings and then use join to combine them like so

```
def sentenceGenerator(a):
    print ' '.join(filter((lambda x: type(x) is str), a)) 

sentenceGenerator(["Mulan", "and", 5, "Aladdin", "is", True, "Quality"])

Mulan and Aladdin is Quality
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't familiar with lambda you could use built-in map function:

```
lst = ["Mulan", "and", 5, "Aladdin", "is", True, "Quality"]
str = " ".join(map(str, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

just this -

```
def sentenceGenerator(a):
    newList = []
    for string in a:
        if isinstance(string, str) or isinstance(string, unicode):
            newList.append(string)
    print(newList)
```